# Wordpress Cron function stops halfway but runs manually?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, cron

To give a bit of background to my project first, I have a Wordpress website of which I have turned off the cron by tweaking the wp-config to:

`define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);`

I then set up a cron to the wp-cron file on the server to call the file every minute and this has been working as expected and as I need it to.

I use a plugin called 'Wp-Crontrol' to set up my own cron calls on various functions within my functions file.

`Memory Limit: 2048M`

`PHP max execution time: 2700`

**The Issue**

I have one function in particular that takes a report from a remote source and loops through each line entering each line into the database using the **$wpdb** class. If i place the function on a php page and go to it the function works perfectly as expected and enters all 6900 rows into the database after some time.

The way I would like it to work is to run a cron on that function (like I do with so many other things with no problems) but the issue is that when I set it up via cron it only seems to insert around 3000 rows before it just stops with no errors logged?

I am struggling to work out why running it manually would work perfectly but a scheduled cron of the same function during the night would only do half the job and not finish, stopping half way through?

I have turned on all error logging I can think of but nothing shows?

Comment: Have since tried adding ignore_user_abort(true); to the function but that has not helped.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress "cron" jobs are not the same thing as a system cron job. For instance, unless you have a high traffic site, it's pretty much impossible to set a gaurenteed 60 second cron with WordPress. WordPress crons are activated when someone puts an HTTP request into the system. A system cron runs off a daemon that runs in system memory. They are just different concepts and work differently.

Comment: That is why I disabled WP Cron and ran the file manually via the server which is a common technique to get around the issue you mention. This way the cron is guaranteed to run every 60 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was processing time but for some reason it would not flag at all in any error messages. After I thinned out long processes it started behaving as expected.